# Shell script: execute 2 commands and keep first running

Tags: linux, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script for my docker image where:

1. a mssqql server is started
2. database setup happens

However with my current script my sql server instance stops as soon as the data import is done. Could anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
database=myDB
wait_time=30s
password=myPw

exec /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
echo importing data will start in $wait_time...
sleep $wait_time
echo importing data...

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 0.0.0.0 -U sa -P $password -i ./init.sql

for entry in "table/*.sql"
do
  echo executing $entry
  /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 0.0.0.0 -U sa -P $password -i $entry
done

for entry in "data/*.csv"
do
  shortname=$(echo $entry | cut -f 1 -d '.' | cut -f 2 -d '/')
  tableName=$database.dbo.$shortname
  echo importing $tableName from $entry
  /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp $tableName in $entry -c -t',' -F 2 -S 0.0.0.0 -U sa -P $password
done
```

Comment: It would help if you include part of a `*.csv` file  and also the output (echoed) messages of your script.

Comment: @Sergio the steps work just fine. The problem is my docker container stops as soon as the last step's done whilst I need the sql server to keep running.

Comment: Seems like `set -m` does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I need to add `set -m` to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any clear mistakes in your shell script. I am just advising you the below:-

1. Try to run the server from the current shell of the script without `exec`

   ```
    /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
   ```
2. Put some echo in both the loop statements to check what is going on there.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Oh the whole thing works fine. The issue I have is that once all the import tablename from entries have finished the whole shell script stops including my sqlserver instance. Although maybe that's docker related